# Email notifications not receiving for community user

Tags: customer-community

I am facing one issue of not getting email notifications on email id on creation/update of email id of community user or whenever I am sending emails from community using single email message.
This is happening in Full Copy sandbox, from Dev sandbox, i am successfully receiving mails.

need pointers for this as i have already connected to Firewall team and they mentioned they are not blocking any IP for emails.

Comment: What is the Deliverability setting in your Full Copy sandbox?

Comment: Deliverability is 'All Email'